# Email signoff alternatives

Tags: email

I'm a teacher at a small Swedish university, and I often communicate via email. In the beginning of a course, I tend to try to be somewhat formal, which isn't really my personal style, but soon I drop all the "Dear" for "Hi" instead. In class, I'm informal and quite personal.

My "problem" is the sign-offs. I've simply more or less had enough of "Regards" (although I use it anyway to be safe) but don't really feel too comfortable with BR/Best/Cheers either, at least not in the beginning of a course. (My students are all second-language learners of English.)

Any better ideas, anyone?

Stefan

Comment: I rarely include any kind of traditional sign-off (unless I'm being formal). I finish my last paragraph and then simply write my first name on its own line at the end. If I want to say something specific in conclusion, that's at the end of my last paragraph instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your problem really well.
What about one of the following:

> Greetings
>
> Have a nice day/evening/week/weekend

And in case of some emails maybe also:

> Good luck
>
> All the best
>
> Thanks/Thank you (for ...)

Comment: Thanks, devaga. I like "Have a nice..." (except for with "day" which sounds too much like a clerk-in-a-store phrase to me. "Thanks" is also great when there's something where a thank you is called for. "All the best" is good most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

I use "cordially" for people I don't know personally but toward whom I want to act friendly.

Comment: I appreciate your help; however, most of my students are probably unfamiliar with "cordially" and, besides, I'm looking for more personal sign-offs. Those are people I meet several times a week in class and with whom I have a relaxed relationship where don't shy away from making fun of myself.